# Apache Storm: Custom logging

Tags: java, logging, logback, apache-storm

I want to modify Storms logback/cluster.xml so that it will write to different files depending on an ID.

Looking at the info I need to change the cluster.xml and add a Sifting Appender. Reference [HERE](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender)

**Main Question**
Is this the best/correct method? 
An example?

I will need to add in:

```
 MDC.put("userid", "Alice");
 logger.debug("Alice says hello");
```

**Example Help**

For the example I cannot seem to get it writing to a file. I use a default logback.xml in the classpath. I do not pass in the arg and load the config as I assume it will be found in the classpath. But then no file is written?

```
<configuration>

<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <!-- in the absence of the class attribute, it is assumed that the desired 
        discriminator type is ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator -->
    <discriminator>
        <key>userid</key>
        <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${userid}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>$/Users/Stuart/Desktop/main.log</file>
            <append>false</append>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%d [%thread] %level %mdc %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache storm does not use the default process for loading log files. Depending on the version you are using it will either have `log4j` `log4j2` or very briefly `logback` directory for the configuration files.

You will have to modify either the `cluster.xml` or the `worker.xml` or both in order to get configuration to register.